# Package-scoped variable

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is there any way to define a variable to be used only in a package, without exporting it to the client or the server? For example,

```
//In /packages/fooPackage/foo.js
packageScopedValue = 'foo';

//In /packages/fooPackage/package.js
api.export('packageScopedValue', 'package');

//In /packages/fooPackage/other.js
doStuffWith(packageScopedValue);
```

Without polluting any other scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A package-scoped var is any global that you don't export. If I say `foo = "RAAARR"` (no `var`) in `pack.js` and `console.log(foo)` in `pack2.js`, you'll see `RAAARR` appear. That's because meteor essentially concatenates each js file in the order you give it & *then* wraps it in an IFFE.

Note that load order does matter!!

```
api.addFiles(['pack.js', 'pack2.js'], 'client'); //works
api.addFiles(['pack2.js', 'pack.js'], 'client'); //undefined
```